# Problems with Firebase cloud functions

Tags: firebase, api, google-cloud-functions, postman

I'm trying to call my backend service hosted with cloud functions but there's a problem when I try to call my apis with Postman...
When I call the endpoint "..../api/auth/login" I receive this response:

```
{
    "message": "Firebase: Error (auth/requests-from-referer-<empty>-are-blocked.)."
}
```

I've already posted about this problem but no one could help me, so I hope that somebody knows what's going on and how I can solve this.

Have a nice day.
I've tried to add the Referer header but it doesn't work.

Okay I may have found something really strange on Postman.
When I include the header "Referer" as I said before the header is not sent with the request!
Here's the proof
[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Referer` and some other headers (e.g. `Host`, `Connection`, etc.) are restricted when interacted with via JavaScript.

When running Postman from a browser, you'll need to make use of [Postman Interceptor](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/capturing-request-data/interceptor/) to grant Postman the ability to change these headers.